# How can I make a for-loop with array of doubles?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, double

I'm trying to make a for-loop with an array of doubles, but it just doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
double[] myDoubleArray = new double[10];
double piValue = 3.141592;

for (double i = 0; i < 10; piValue+) {
    myDoubleArray[i] += i;
}

System.out.println(myDoubleArray[2]);
System.out.println(myDoubleArray[5]);
```

Comment: You don't need double for iteration/index variable "i" which is int.

Comment: `piValue+` ? What was that supposed to be?

Comment: What do you want the result of the loop to be?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. That's an obvious reason it doesn't work. Consider reading up on how to use a for loop first. https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/for-loop

Comment: Explain what are you trying to do, more clearly, because this code can't run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually for array indexing use int. You can follow below code

```
    double[] myDoubleArray = new  double[10]; 
    double piValue = 3.141592; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
          myDoubleArray[i] = piValue + i; 
    }
 System.out.println(myDoubleArray[2]);

 System.out.println(myDoubleArray[5]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still studying arrays, so I still don't have much knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
    myDoubleArray[i] = Math.PI + i;
}
```

This populates your array of double values, starting with Pi, and incrementing by one for each of ten elements.

Comment: You should accept an answer here (not necessarily mine).  This is how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your array if a double array, the indexes that correspond to each position are still int primitives.

```
double[] doubleArray = {2.45, 4.45};

for(int i = 0; i < doubleArray.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(doubleArray[i]); //Doing something with the double value
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm still new to all that array stuff, so thank you!